# Thymeleaf + Spring boot как избежать создания экземляра при GET запросе

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, freemarker

Изучаю Spring и наткнулся на непонимание

Есть форма с двумя полями "имя" и "возраст" при отправке которой создается объект User и кладется в список который потом отображается на главной страничке

все хорошо но в связке Thymeleaf + Spring boot существует необходимость создавать экземляр пользовательской модели при каждом GET запросе как в примере ниже 
т.е объект создается дважды прежде чем попасть в список и как по мне это не очень хорошо

При этом при использовании Freemarker параметр User в GET запросе не нужен, т.е объект создается только один раз, что на мой взгляд более правильно

Так вот, как сделать так (используя Thymeleaf) чтобы объект НЕ создавался при каждом GET запросе?

```java
 @GetMapping("/new")
    public String add(User user){ // первое создание объекта
        return "new";
    }
```

```java
@PostMapping("/new")
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute User user) { // второе создание объекта
        users.add(user);
        return "redirect:/home";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Два раза как такого объект не создается. На самом деле ваш код я бы немного переработал бы (чуть-чуть усложним), чтобы лучше понималось.

```
@GetMapping("/new")
public ModelAndView getNew(){
  ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
  modelAndView.setViewName("new");
  modelAndView.addAttribute("user", new User());
  return modelAndView;
}

@PostMapping("/new")
public String postNew(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {

  //некоторый код

  users.add(user);
  return "redirect:/home";
}
```

В первом случае (`@GetMapping`), мы передаем в форму либо пустой объект (`new User()`), в который будем что-то писать, либо уже заполненый объект, данные из которого мы будем использовать на странице (Пример: `modelAndView.addAttribute("user", userService.findAll())`).

Во втором случае (`@PostMapping`), мы говорим Spring, что при POST-запросе мы должны из формы получить данные, которые должны записаться в объект `User`.

Как такого, можно и не передавать объект `new User()` в форму. Тогда вам надо будет самому написать в html-форме в каждом аттрибуте ввода данных `id` и `name` (вместо простого `th:field="user.name"`, как пример) да такой, чтобы при отправке формы, Spring смог сам разложить полученные данные в каждую переменную Вашего объекта.